# UITableViewCell memory allocation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, memory-management

I am not sure about the `tableView` memory allocation process using `reuseIdentifier` `static` or not inside `tableView` `delegate` method.

Let suppose if we have 20 count of array which returns from method `numberOfRowsInSection` method then how many `cell` will be allocated in memory after `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method by calling `[UITableViewCell alloc]` `alloc` method at a time.

Example code:

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    return 20;   // array count
}

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){ cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]; 
        // how many cell will be alloc here
    }

// configure cell
}
```

Any useful clarification will be appreciated thanks for your time as well.

Comment: What is the `Height` of row?

Comment: @pkc456 `height` is by `default` thanks for your time ..

Comment: I tried to add this as a comment, but it was too long. So please check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39406550/988169).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the initial time, when your table view first visible on the view (say it is showing 5 cells on the screen at a time), 5 cells will be allocated. When you scroll down, instead of instantiating new ones, table view is reusing the already existing ones using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. So it means 5 cells are in memory only.

Thus, A `UITableView` will normally `allocate` just enough `UITableViewCell` objects to display the content visible in the table.

This design pattern is known as [Object Pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern).

Comment: Great explanation +1  :)

Comment: @JaywantKhedkar Glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[tableView visibleCells] count]`, which returns numbers of the table cells that are visible then **that much cells will be allocated**. When you scroll down, instead of creating new tableviewcell, table view is reusing the already existing ones using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is helps to use less memory.
**Example :**
If the screen can fit 5 table cells then with reuse you only need to have 5 table cells allocated in memory even if the table has 1000 entries.

Comment: thanks @nssam, where i put this line of code to count visible cell ?